# Checking out repository with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

I am trying to check out the following repository with TortoiseSVN (I am pretty new to version control software):

http://carrot2.svn.sourceforge.net/

For this I go to SVN checkout and put in this URL as the URL of the repository, but get the following error:

> > > Command checkout from http://carrot2.svn.sourceforge.net, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
> > >
> > > ErrorOPTIONS of 'http://carrot2.svn.sourceforge.net': 200 OK (http://carrot2.svn.sourceforge.net)
> > >
> > > Finished

How would I properly check out the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open that URL in your browser, you'll see it's a regular web page, not a Subversion repository. Find the right URL at http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=85379

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I overlooked that

Comment: Also, you will probably want to check out /trunk or a specific branch from the url. Otherwise you will get a bunch of copies of the entire project and take up an enormous amount of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a long time since I used Tortoise, but I could add the checkout from the repository you had mentioned in your question ( In Mac using Cornerstone). I think the problem is, you need to specify the protocol. By default svn repository use "svn://" protocol, but this repository uses http://, so you might have to mention this while adding this repository in your svn client.

Edit: This is the svn checkout url for the repository: svn co https://carrot2.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/carrot2 carrot2

Comment: Subversion does not use any protocol by default. If you want to use `svn:` you have to configure the appropriate server. SourceForge uses HTTPS.

Comment: You are correct. May be what I was trying to say did not come out correctly. In my subversion client, I need to mention if the svn server is a File Repository, Svn Repository or Http repository. ( I am using cornerstone). So i was of opinion that the Tortoise needs to be told about the server protocol also.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is located here:

https://carrot2.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/carrot2

You are just looking at viewvc paths.  You might want to just pull a trunk or a branch rather then the whole repo, depending on how much code is there.